# Spark - Writing into HDFS does not complete successfully

Tags: hdfs, apache-spark

My question is similar to ([Spark writing to hdfs not working with the saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27072911/spark-writing-to-hdfs-not-working-with-the-saveasnewapihadoopfile-method/))! I am using Spark 1.1.0 on CDH 5.2.1

I am trying to save a file to hdfs system through saveAsTextFile method from Spark. The job completes successfully but when I look into the folder path, I see _temporary folder with data files inside it in various tasks and attempt folder. This tells me Spark is quitting the job as succeeded even before the files are completely moved into hdfs in the right output folder. This is the same issue with saveAsParquetFile method too. Please let me know if you have any idea about this?

Thanks

Comment: Do you call sc.stop (sc is the Spark context) at the end of the main function ?

Comment: No I dont. I was under the impression that saveAsParquetFile will create all the files in the respective output path and add _SUCCESS file there too, which is not happening. Can you please let me know how sc.stop will help for this issue?

Comment: I have experienced some issues with files under the spark application history directory. The sc.stop command let the driver wait for the application to complete all pending operations. If you just let the main method terminate you could interrupt the process abnormally. In my case, the APPLICATION_COMPLETE file was not being created without sc.stop.

Comment: Thanks Nicola. I will try this and let you know how it goes.